# MySQL join with AVG calculation

Tags: mysql, join, average

Is this possible?

I have a table which stores articles

I have another table which stores users ratings of the articles, each row is a rating which references the article

I want to get the average rating score for articles in the past 30 days:

```
SELECT `ex`.`article_id` , `ex`.`date` , `ex`.`title` , `r`.AVG(`rating`)
FROM `exclusive` `ex`
JOIN `ratings` `r` ON `ex`.`article_id` = `r`.`article_id`
WHERE `ex`.`date` > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

As you can see I'm trying to reference the 'rating' with the AVG function which is causing the issue. I think the issue is that the rating needs to be calculated before the select is made some I'm beginning to doubt if it's possible?

Answer (score 1):

You have to indicate how the data should be grouped, to indicate which groups to use for the average calculation, e.g.:

```
SELECT `ex`.`article_id` , `ex`.`title` , AVG(r.rating)
FROM `exclusive` `ex`
JOIN `ratings` `r` ON `ex`.`article_id` = `r`.`article_id`
WHERE `ex`.`date` > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY ex.article_id
```

Comment: This solution will not average ratings,  incorporating date will average by each date, and incorporating titles,  you are aggregating each rating,  so you'll get _n_ averages the same _n_reviews.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks but what is 'group by' doing, it seems that if i change the column for the group by this determines how the results are ordered? Of course it does more than this but I can't see what?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off:

Change

```
..., r.AVG(rating)
```

To

```
..., AVG(r.rating)
```

And add a group by clause at the end of your query:

```
...
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

---

It should look like:

```
SELECT `ex`.`article_id` , `ex`.`date` , `ex`.`title` , AVG(`r`.`rating`)
FROM `exclusive` `ex`
JOIN `ratings` `r` ON `ex`.`article_id` = `r`.`article_id`
WHERE `ex`.`date` > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Awesome that's great, what does 'group by' do, I'm not familiar with this syntax.

Comment: Functions like AVG, SUM, COUNT etc are *aggregate* functions, which give a single value for a *group* of rows that share the same values in the non-aggregate columns, but you must specify that other columns in a group by clause. The SQL standard allows you to use the column *number* (in the query) instead of the column name/expression.

Comment: Thank you, this example made the penny drop for me: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that in order to average the rating you should aggregate itś dimensions,  mainly by date,  say grouping the last 30 days as you request,  but to do so you should avoid aggregating by each review (title) and each date.  Try this:

```
    SELECT `ex`.`article_id` , AVG( case when `ex`.`date` ` > NOW( ) - INTERVAL 30 DAY    
    then `r`.`rating` else 0 end) as 30_day_rating_average  FROM `exclusive` `ex` JOIN `ratings` `r` ON `ex`.`article_id` = `r`.`article_id` group by 1
```

You can also get a column with article name,  instead of just article id.